# Mouse Cursor Larger when HDR mode is off, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse-cursor, hdr

Have an odd one here.

I got a 4k TV and used it as a monitor. A Hisense H9G. My secondary monitor is an Asus monitor. Card is a Nividia 1080. All running on windows 10.
Because i don't expect my now 2-generations behind card to do 4k content well(specifically games) and all the current gen are sold out, i'm currently just running things at 1920x1080.

The odd one is either i had not noticed it prior, or messing around with settings made this happen, but i noticed when i had the "Windows HD Color" disabled my mouse cursor was huge, as if it was trying to scale it up for a 4k monitor, on a 2k monitor. Turned HDR mode on and suddenly its fine.

I feel like this is just an issue of windows or something else recognizing the monitor incorrectly, because i checked the "Scale and Layout" and its set to 100%, even set it up then down again for good measure; and all the actual APP sizes don't scale up/down with this setting.

I can generally just live with it on HDR mode, i mostly was curious if someone could explain what happened here because i could've sworn is was fine before; and this issue seems so specific i can't find anything that really matches what I'm seeing here.

The only other thing to mention is the tv had a firmware update this morning and while everything was fine initially when i re-tested the HDR mode (before the update there was some color issues so i wanted to see if they were fixed), and swapped it back and suddenly noticed the larger cursor; which looks extra odd moving between the screens as one looks fine.

Comment: Update to this question. Now swapping it off of HDR results in correctly sized pointer and such. So i'm not sure. I'm getting a feeling something was just not recognizing it correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.